# MongoDB C# driver slow performance

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm testing MongoDB and it's c# client for a project I am working on. I've done some benchmarking and for my test c# project created a simple application which instantiates 10.000.000 objects and inserts them into a MongoDB collection. There are around 10 fields for each document. These fields have randomly assigned values that are either very short strings (2 or 3 chars) or integers.

After a few minutes it successfully stored all of the 10.000.000 documents. Now I used the mongo shell and the supplied rest service to do some simple queries. I was searching for specific strings (like 'AAA' or 'BBB') and it took around 200-300ms and returned up to 10.000 results (set some limits). After creating the indexes it only takes a maximum of 20ms which is the performance I want since it will be a read heavy application.

Pretty happy so far. Then I tried creating the same query in c# client and it always takes at least 200ms to execute. Even when calling the same query multiple times.

I've tested both on two different systems.
- One is Intel xeon e5 1660 v3 with 48GB of RAM and an enterprise level SSD
- The second is on i7, 8gb of ram and a entry level SSD

Currently I am getting the same results on both PCs.

I know that the first query/connection can be costly and take some time but I've made the same query run up to 50 times and it's always returning results in the same - 200 - 250ms range.

After some testing on both machines I decided to start from scratch. I created a simple project (attached the code below). And tried querying based on only 1000 results that I inserted. I'm getting the same slow query times. A simple 'return all results' query takes 250 - 300ms. Even when assigning a limit and only fetching one item.

My insert code:

```
        _client = new MongoClient();
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("search");

        collection = _database.GetCollection<TestVote>("testVotes");

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            TestVote vote = new TestVote();
            vote.postNumber = RandomString(2); // the id of the politician
            vote.randomSeed = _rng.Next(0, 5000);

            collection.InsertOneAsync(vote);
        }
```

TestVote class:

```
class TestVote
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public string postNumber;
    public int randomSeed;
}
```

My query code:

```
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        //var filter = Builders<TestVote>.Filter.Eq("postNumber", "AA"); 
        // ^ this only returns one results and still takes 300ms
        //var result = await collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var result = await collection.Find(_ => true).Limit(5).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs + " " + result.postNumber);
```

I have tried the commented part of the query code aswell with the same results

Comment: Can you look at your mongo log and see if the C# query is being reported as a slow running query (100ms+ by default I believe) and post what query it is trying to run. If its not showing up make sure the collection is being profiled at at least level 1 so that slow running queries show up.

Comment: @ThrowsException seems like the first query is always taking a bit more. I did not think the connection could be this costly. I've done random queries for each search (each query had different parameters) on the same collection and they are always super fast (10ms) after the first initial query which on my asp.net website take exactly 1.01 seconds to load. Each time.

Comment: Are you sure its actually the connection to the database thats taking time and not your asp.net site waking up? Are you running this site with IIS express in visual studio or hosting it on a full instance of IIS running in release mode. What part of the application is the code to find actually located.